# Why is BeforeUpdate event firing when I change a control in VBA?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have an Access form which is opened via a button click from another form. I have a Form_Current event which updates several controls on that form via VBA. For some reason, this is causing the BeforeUpdate event to fire after Form_Current finishes, even though the MS help doc says that changing controls in VBA does not trigger this event. I have managed to isolate at least one of the lines which will trigger this event:

```
txtEventID = gblEventID
```

where txtEvent ID is the name of a control, and gblEventID is a module-level variable. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

In case you want a look at the whole sub:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If (Me.NewRecord = True) Then
        Dim lookupNum As Integer

        txtEventID = gblEventID
        lookupNum = DLookup("Max(Subplot_Num)", "tbl_Subplots", "Event_ID = " & txtEventID.Value) + 1

        If (IsNull(lookupNum)) Then
            txtSubplotNum = "1"
        Else
            txtSubplotNum = lookupNum
        End If

    End If

    If xboPoaching.Value = False Then txtPoachingNotes.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: which control's Before_Update event is firing? And what, if any, is that control's record source or control source? I've seen weird stuff like this before in access - I'm hoping I can help you. I know how frustrating it is

Comment: This is the Before_Update event for the entire form. So Form_Current sets a control's value to an integer, and after that sub finishes running, the Before_Update sub is immediately run. I know that that line in Form_Current is the culprit beacuse I've commented everything else out and still had it trigger Before_Update. The control source for the control whose value is set is bound to an integer field in a table.

Comment: Now that you've asked that, I'm wondering if the MS help doc on Before Update means that the **control's** Before_Update event won't fire if changed in VBA, but the one for the **entire form** will. But that begs another question: how can I run code that will only trigger right before a user moves to a new record, and not after they update a control?

Comment: try this - set the form's controls' values more explicitly in the VBA. So, rather than `txtEventID = gblEventID`, try `txtEventID.Value = gblEventID`. Same with other controls like `txtSubplotNum` etc.

Comment: Just tried that - no change. But I adopted the code of Gustav below, and now BeforeUpdate is only triggered when the form first loads, but not on any subsequent new records. Strange... still looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify/reduce that code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim lookupNum As Integer

    If Me.NewRecord = True Then    
        lookupNum = Nz(DMax("Subplot_Num", "tbl_Subplots", "Event_ID = " & gblEventID & ""), 0) + 1
        txtSubplotNum = lookupNum
    End If

    If xboPoaching.Value = False Then 
        txtPoachingNotes.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

As best I can make out, it seems like if you change a value in a control programmatically, the Before_Update Event for that control will not fire, but the Before_Update Event for form which houses that control will. MS docs are hazy on this, but it seems to be consistent in my testing.